# How to change default dcc.Graph template in Plotly Dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to change the default plotly template to 'seaborn' or 'plotly_dark'. While it works in plotly, it does not seem to work in Dash that uses plotly. It still shows the default plotly template even after specifying template='plotly_dark'.

Here is the code without specifying template:

```
return dcc.Graph(
    id='example-graph',
    figure={
        'data': [
            {'x': df_most_lines.Cast, 'y': df_most_lines.Lines, 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'input_data'}
        ],
        'layout':  { 'paper_bgcolor':'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                'plot_bgcolor':'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            'title': 'WHO USED THE MOSE LINES?'
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `go.Figure()` instead of the dictionary your code should work:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Graph(figure=go.Figure(data=go.Bar(x=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], y=[1, 2, 3, 4]),
                               layout=dict(template='plotly_dark'))),

])

app.run_server(debug=False)
```